# setting run / baseDirectory from command line

Tags: sbt

The run / baseDirectory can be set in build.sbt as follows:

run / baseDirectory := file("path")

Is it possible to set this path from the command line? If not, it would be a very useful feature to add. Thanks.

Comment: SO is not a feature request site nor technical support, so if there was no such feature you would have to go ask sbt authors not people _answering questions_ on Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
sbt> set run/baseDirectory := sbt.file("path")
```

or

```
> sbt 'set run/baseDirectory := sbt.file("path")' shell # or other command
```